# Fold the parent node until mouseout its children nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to make a responsive navigation content,
when I mouseover a "level-1" title, it will unfold its sub-titles,
while mouseout the sub-titles, it will fold them all.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style></style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li class="level-1"> <a href="">HTML</a>
    <ul> <li> <a href="">1.Abstract Sections</a>
             <ul>
                <li> <a href="">1.Header</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">2.Footer</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">3.A.Main</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">4.B1.Nav</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">5.B2.Aside</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="">2.Block</a>
            <ul> <li> <a href="">Headers</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">Paragraphs</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">List</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">Table</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">Quotation</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li><!-- html -->
<li class="level-1"> <a href="">CSS</a>
    <ul> <li><a href="">Boxes</a>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="">Margin</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">Padding</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">Border</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Layout</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("body>ul>li>ul").hide();
    $("body>ul>li>a").on("mouseover",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // alert("clicked");
        $(e.target).next().show();
    });
    $("body>ul>li").on("mouseout",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // alert("clicked");
        $(e.target).next().hide();
    });

})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The codes works partially, but when I mouseout the level-1 title, it's folded. I want it stay unfolded until I leave its sub-titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any JS for this as it can be done much more simply and effectively by utilising the CSS `:hover` selector to hide/show the relevant `li` element based on the one which the user hovers over:

```css
ul > li > ul { 
  display: none; 
}

ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="level-1">
    <a href="">HTML</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">1.Abstract Sections</a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="">1.Header</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="">2.Footer</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="">3.A.Main</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="">4.B1.Nav</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="">5.B2.Aside</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">2.Block</a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="">Headers</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="">Paragraphs</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="">List</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="">Table</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="">Quotation</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-1">
    <a href="">CSS</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Boxes</a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="">Margin</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="">Padding</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="">Border</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Layout</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: incredible, beyond my wild imagination~~